# SSRS 2008 R2 Matrix Report Calculated column has value even though calculation fields are blank

Tags: reporting-services, matrix, sql-server-2008-r2

I have created a matrix report with the following set up where ReportDate is a Parent Group

```
             ||            Report Date              || (group on ReportDate)
|Type | Name || Size(GB) | Used (GB) | Percent Used ||
```

The report could show data over a range of 30 days (ReportDate) ie. BeginDate = 12/01/2013 EndDate = 12/30/2013

All items work correctly except for when a new type is added during that report date cycle (12/15/2013)  The report columns show accurate information from the time the new type is created, but when there is actually no data in Size (GB) and Used (GB) I get erroneous data in my calculated columns Percent Used and Daily Delta.

I am using this formula for the Percent Used cell.
=IIF(Fields!Size_GB_.Value = 0,0, Fields!UsedSpace_GB_.Value/IIF(Fields!Size_GB_.Value=0,1,Fields!Size_GB_.Value))

I have tried using IsNothing and get the same result.

Here is an example of what I receive

```
             ||             12/14/2013              ||          12/15/2013              || 
|Type | Name || Size(GB) | Used (GB) | Percent Used || Size(GB) | Used (GB) | Percent Used 
 DATE   SET1                             62.40 %       3,072.1      210.2      6.84 %
```

Sorry I don't have a good enough reputation to post images.

Comment: You can post a link to an image and we can edit the images into your question. Please do that. I'm having a hard time understand the issue in your question as it is.